# Foxpro SQL Query for > 24 Criteria

Tags: sql, foxpro

I'm using OleDB to connect to a FoxPro DBF database.   I need to query a table for all items with column = key1 or key2 or key3...... key2000.

FoxPro apparently doesn't like long queries....

I've tried both:

```
where (col like "key1") or (col like "key2") or ..... (col like "key2000")
```

and

```
where col in ("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4".... "key2000")
```

The first solution fails for "query too complex".  The second key fails for too many elements in the in range (apparently the max is 24).  This seems absurd...

Is there a way for me to construct my query without multiple reads?

Thanks.

Comment: You're exceeding FoxPro's query length limit.  The OLEDB/ODBC engines are really lightweight versions of the FoxPro data engine in drag (stripped of just about everything non-data-engine).  The query length limit is something silly, like 8k characters (can't remember off the top of my head) so most likely it's larger than it wants to see, hence "query too complex".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to push your criteria into a temporary table or criteria table and query from that

```
Create Table Criteria  (
                        UserSessionId ...
                        , KeyValue ....
                        )


Select ...
From MyMainTable
    Join Criteria
        On Criteria.KeyValue = MyMainTable.col
            And Criteria.UserSessionId = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1) Use multiple IN clauses with 24 values in each

```
WHERE col IN (,,,,) OR col IN (,,,,) OR col IN (,,, )
```

2) Put the 2000 values in a comma-delimited string and use

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ?string LIKE '%'+col+'%'
```